# Thresholds for Infinite Expected Cluster Size/Diameter

Tags: probability-theory, percolation

In a many infinite random graphs, such as lattices, there is a non-trivial threshold $p_c$ above which, if we independently and identically select sites or bonds to belong to a set, we will obtain an infinite connected cluster all of whose sites or bonds respectively belong to the set. This implies non-trivial respective thresholds at which the expected size and diameter of the cluster containing a site becomes infinite. Are these in general equal to $p_c$? If so, will infinite values arrive at $p_c$, in $(p_c,1]$, or would it depend on the graph? If we choose our graph to be the rooted directed tree in which every vertex has countably infinitely many out-neighbours and weaken our i.i.d. condition so that only the sets of outneighbours are i.i.d., then we have a branching process. Diameter is the maximum eccentricity and the eccentricity of the root is just the length of time before extinction. We can show using Markov's Inequality that when the expected number of offspring is less than $1$, the expected extinction time is finite, and since the probability of extinction is less than $1$ when the expected number of offspring is greater than $1$, in this case it is infinite. So a related question is whether the expected extinction time is infinite when the expected number of offspring in a branching process is $1$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but for a large class of graph called non-amenable, there exists a phase in which there exist infinitely many infite clusters, and a threshold p_u above which the infinite clusters coalesce into one unique infinite cluster, for trees (or eventually any infinitely ended transitive graphs) p_u = 1. Hope this helps. refer to R Lyons and Y Peres book.

Comment: That's a different phase for a stronger condition, but I'm asking among other things for a phase in which, for a given site, the expected size of the cluster containing that site (set the size of the cluster containing a site to zero if it is not in a cluster) is infinite. For instance, in an infinite binary tree we have at $p_c=\frac{1}{2}$ that the expected size of the cluster containing a site is infinite, but there are almost surely no infinite clusters. However the difference between infinite clusters and infinite expected cluster size is only at one point here.

Comment: hum, so to be clear, it's conjectured (but quite largely proven) that yes there are no infinite cluster @p_c but that the expectation of the size of the cluster is infinite. this is the same for all edges assuming transitivity. the transition is meant to be sharp because precisely the cluster size and the expected size explode at the same point (with the notable execption of what happens at p_c).